# Ruby on Rails - Validates_inclusion_of in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create validations, where it only allows values that are in an array.

```
validates_inclusion_of :valid_number, :in =>[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

That works, but what I want is something like this

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

validates_inclusion_of :valid_number, :in => numbers
```

When I type that I always get a NoMethodError. This leads me to believe maybe I need a different type of variable (instance, class, global).

Just a heads-up, I know there's a way to validate numericality in a range, but that's not what I'm looking for. I just picked numbers because it was quicker to type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be able to make it a constant:

```
NUMBERS = (1..10).to_a
validates_inclusion_of :valid_number, :in => NUMBERS
```

<s>This might work as well, but i haven't tested :)</s>

**Edit** Nope, doesn't work. The below throws an error.

```
self.numbers = (1..10).to_a
validates_inclusion_of :valid_number, :in => numbers
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I get undefined local variable or method numbers. Do we need an @ symbol before the variable name or make self.numbers a method? Of course, I also had my validates statement before the  numbers statement. Should it be the other way around? Never mind, that doesn't work either.